# What are the possibillities to Resign your UWP packages?

Tags: certificate, uwp

When we create a new UWP project, a certificate is generated. How can we resign the package with some other certificate?

Comment: You mean the Temporary cert? or the developer cert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to project properties and to signing tap. You can:

1. Create a new Temp Cert
2. Sign with a new Cert
3. Sign with a existing Cert

[image]

Comment: Is the certificate defined here used if you choose to create packages that are not for the store by going to "Store > Create App Packages" and choose "No" when asked whether the package is for the store? 

Or do you still need to sign those manually after creation using SignTool that comes with the SDK?